# Images in cURL email with HTML not resizing

Tags: html, smtp, base64, filemaker

I am currently trying to send an e-mail with cURL through SMTP. The body is a .txt containing the HTML. The inline attachments (in this case, images) are being inserted by converting them to base64 format standard RFC-2045. The images are all sent correctly (the whole email is), however, they are not being resized as it is specified in the style attribute.

The example of the image insert of the HTML is as below.

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..." style="width:100px;"/>
```

I've already tried to set both width and height - either setting height to "auto" or calculating it through rule of three.

I have also tried using internal CSS like so, but didn't work:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #imgDisplay{
            width: 100px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<img id="imgDisplay" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..."/>
</body>
```

I have little experience with HTML, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something, I've been searching an answer for hours but no success so far. I should also add that I am sending this email through FileMaker Pro Advanced 18 using its native cURL function. I have another email with a lot of HTML and attachments and it works perfectly, however, this is the first time I'm trying to send images in the body.

The full HTML is below:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:120px"><span style="font-size:24px"><strong><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"> name2 </span></strong></span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:90px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:120px"><span style="font-size:24px"><strong><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"> name2 </span></strong></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="height:230px; width:105px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-color:#000000; height:63px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:100px"><img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..." style="width:100px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong> value1 &euro;</strong></span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"> value2 &euro;</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
            <table cellpadding="12" style="height:230px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:60px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:60px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..." style="width:40px;height:40px" /></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong>M&ecirc;s</strong></span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong>Ano</strong></span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="height:230px; width:105px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-color:#000000; height:63px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:100px"><img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..." style="width:100px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong> value3 &euro;</strong></span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"> value4 &euro;</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table cellpadding="15" style="height:230px; width:105px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:63px; text-align:center">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong> diff1 &euro;</strong></span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:16px"> diff2 &euro;</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the `<img>` tag attributes `width` and `height`:

```
<img width="100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..."/>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!! Can you tell me why setting the size with attributes works, but with style doesn't?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the mail client you are using. Actually it should work as you have set it, but with base64 images the behaviour can be quite strange.

Comment: Google for "Email Client CSS Support", maybe it will help with other problems.